# How to hit and get response soap api of sabre for hotels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sabre

I'm new to **Sabre dev studio API's** and try to use in my **ruby project** but I'm unable to hit APIs. If you have any idea then please let me explain integration of ***SOAP API of Sabre***. I have spent lot of hours in doing this. 
I have use `gem savon` but unable to get the response from sabre. I have use this code

```
 str ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
            <eb:ConversationId/>
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">999999</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>1000</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:TimeToLive>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</eb:TimeToLive>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
            <wsse:UsernameToken> 
                <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
                <Organization>IPCC</Organization>
                <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain> 
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <eb:Manifest SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
            <eb:Reference xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="cid:rootelement" xlink:type="simple"/>
        </eb:Manifest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'



client = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: "http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/usg/SessionCreateRQ.wsdl")
@result = client.call(:session_create_rq,:message=>Hash.from_xml(str))
```

When I try to make request this render me with an error

```
(soap-env:Client.InvalidEbXmlMessage) Unable to create envelope from given source: Error on line 1 of document : Element "xmlns:SOAP_ENV" cannot have "xmlns" as its prefix. Nested exception: Element "xmlns:SOAP_ENV" cannot have "xmlns" as its prefix.
```

Please suggest me how I improve this to get the proper response.

Comment: you maust have some response... what do you get?... P.S. you can use `<<-XML.squish .... XML` instead of quotes and then you don't have to parse the string

Comment: I got this error  ,
(soap-env:Client.InvalidEbXmlMessage) Unable to create envelope from given source: Error on line 1 of document : Element "xmlns:SOAP_ENV" cannot have "xmlns" as its prefix. Nested exception: Element "xmlns:SOAP_ENV" cannot have "xmlns" as its prefix.

Comment: And which part is confusing? the error is pretty self-explanatory:  `"xmlns:SOAP_ENV" cannot have "xmlns" as its prefix`

Comment: when I'm removing xmlns then this SOAP_ENV makes error, Undefined prefix SOAP-ENV found.

Comment: and what is the error then?

Comment: Undefined prefix SOAP-ENV found

Comment: Sabre doesn't use the ancient pure ebXML format, it uses the very old and non-standard ebXML over the "SOAP with Atachments" format. `xmlns` is part of SOAP, not ebXML. You probably need to change your proxy's configuration to treat this message as SOAP instead of ebXML

Comment: Wait, what you posted is the *response* from the server that complains the request is wrong, specifically that the XML document itself is wrong. Any XML validator should return an error if a namespace is wrong. Why don't you create a *proxy* instead of trying to send the SOAP message directly? Instead of makin a single call to `SessionCreateRQ`, you end up generating the entire message

Comment: All namespaces have to be declared in a valid XML document, which means that `xmlns` needs to be specified as well. Try adding `xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" ` or `xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11"`  in the root element. `xmlns` is used as the default namespace for any tag that doesn't have a namespace, but in your case all tags have one so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos . I will try this in my code and will discuss more about this.